# How to fix macOS hanging and crashing every time I try to restart or shut down?

Tags: macos, battery, crash, kernel-panic, power-nap

Every time I try to shut down or restart my MacBook Air (Retina, 13-inch, 2020) running macOS Big Sur 11.3.1, the mac keeps spinning for about 5 minutes, and ultimately crashes.

After manually powering on the mac again, the following error log shows:

```
panic(cpu 2 caller 0x...): watchdog timeout: no checkins from watchdogd in 307 seconds (1742 totalcheckins since monitoring last enabled), shutdown in progress
Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
...
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.watchdog(1.0)[...
         com.apple.driver.AppleSMC(3.1.9)[...
            dependency: com.apple.driver.watchdog(1)[...
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[...
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[...

Process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task
Boot args: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev

...
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

**Turning off Power Nap** both while on battery power or while plugged into a power adapter solve the problem. Steps from [Apple support pages](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh40774/11.0/mac/11.0):

1. On your Mac, choose Apple menu  > System Preferences, then click Battery.
2. Do one of the following:

   - Specify Battery settings: Click Battery, then deselect “Enable Power Nap while on battery power”.
   - Specify Power Adapter settings: Click Power Adapter, then deselect “Enable Power Nap while plugged into a power adapter”.